# I have a problem installing activestate python instead of the default. How can I fix it? Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: python, compiling, install-from-source

I am getting this error when trying to run the ./install.sh for ActivePython.  How can I correct this?

```
cd /tmp
wget http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.7.2.5/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xzf ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86.tar.gz
cd ActivePython-2.7.2.5-linux-x86
./install.sh

error:
./INSTALLDIR/bin/python2.7: 2: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Comment: Also: SHELL=/bin/bash

Comment: You don't need to set `SHELL=/bin/bash`; the default shell is already bash.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting that error when I run ./install.sh

Comment: I get this error when I try to run `./install.sh` on a 32 bit system (the tar archive contains a 64 bit version).

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version/architecture?